# Maven pom.xml error while setting up apache spark

Tags: xml, maven, apache-spark, spark-streaming, pom.xml

I am trying to setup apache streaming . In the below pom.xml. when i am adding

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

pom file is getting error,saying :Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - Failure to transfer org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-utils:jar:2.4.0-b34

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    com.iot.app.kafka
    iot-kafka-producer
    1.0.0
    IoT Kafka Producer

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming-kafka_2.10 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.3</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.spark-project.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>unused</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>19.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Kindly someone help me in resolving this issue.Thans in adavnce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use same versions of `spark-core` and `spark-streaming-kafka`. Please, try to change `spark-streaming-kafka` dependency to this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for the input.
I have added the <dependency> you mentioned, and force updated the maven.
It worked.